# mysql monthly sales comparison

Tags: mysql, compare, row, left-join, delta

I have 1 table:

```
 id | year |  quarter  |  month | brand  | sku | total_unit_sales 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 2010 |  1        |  Jan   | Toyota | 123 | 156 
 2  | 2010 |  1        |  Jan   | Toyota | 124 | 77
 3  | 2010 |  1        |  Jan   | Toyota | 125 | 325
 4  | 2010 |  1        |  Feb   | Toyota | 123 | 184 
 5  | 2010 |  1        |  Feb   | Toyota | 124 | 98
 6  | 2010 |  1        |  Feb   | Toyota | 125 | 219 
 7  | 2010 |  1        |  Mar   | Toyota | 123 | 178 
 8  | 2010 |  1        |  Mar   | Toyota | 124 | 101
 9  | 2010 |  1        |  Mar   | Toyota | 125 | 215 
 10 | 2010 |  1        |  Apr   | Toyota | 123 | 216 
 11 | 2010 |  1        |  Apr   | Toyota | 124 | 115
 12 | 2010 |  1        |  Apr   | Toyota | 125 | 278
```

I need to create delta indexes (the percentage of variation one time period to other period) on sales by brand, month, year.  Those indexes are average variation in the last 12 months,  variation in current quarter, last month vs previous month.

I once achieved this in a multi stage way,  creating many summarizing tables and then generating the desired report.  However this was a manual customized process.  Now I need a fully automated way where the data source is updated and the report generated.

I' ve been working on a self join,  however the results are less than desirable,  having in mind that can compare previous price versus newest price by self joining the table with:

```
left join on a.id=b.id+1
```

This is prone to error due to the fact that some months do not gahter sales data of some specific sku,  not sold on that month.

I appreciate your help.  Thanks in advance.  mysql ver 5.5+

Answer (score 0):

Your join approach sounds like a valid way to proceed. You can improve the quality of your figures by using an `outer join`, and IFNULL() to generate sensible values.

Comment: Yes indeed I can estimate a delta by (a.total_unit_sales-ifnull(b.total_unit_sales,0)).  However my issue is related to the way of self joining the table to be able to make the calculations.